# How to convert string to json string and object in java

Tags: java, android

This is My String

```
{Line:1,Direction:incoming,LocalUsername:xxx,AuthUsername:31223,PeerUsername:04232000113,Name:04232000113,Server:23424,Connectime:2189msec,Duration:0msec,DiscBy:Remote,Reason:cancelNormalcallclearing}
```

i want to convert it to json string

```
{"Line":"1","Direction":"incoming","LocalUsername":"xxx","AuthUsername":"31223","PeerUsername":"04232000113","Name":"04232000113","Server":"23424","Connectime":"2189msec","Duration":"0msec","DiscBy":"Remote"}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since it isn't nested, simply add `"` around `:` and `,`, and after `{` and before `}`:

```java
s = s.replaceAll("(?<=[{:,])|(?=[:,}])", "\"");
```

See demo on [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/qAB9gB/1).

Answer (score 2):

Try using Gson library

```java
Gson g = new Gson();
Player p = g.fromJson(jsonString, Player.class)
```

You can also convert a Java object to JSON by using toJson() method as shown below

```java
String str = g.toJson(p);
```

---

If you don't have a POJO representing the data, it can be done generally using `JsonElement`.

*Demo*

```java
String input = "{Line:1,Direction:incoming,LocalUsername:xxx,AuthUsername:31223,PeerUsername:04232000113,Name:04232000113,Server:23424,Connectime:2189msec,Duration:0msec,DiscBy:Remote,Reason:cancelNormalcallclearing}";

Gson g = new Gson();
JsonElement root = g.fromJson(input, JsonElement.class);
String result = g.toJson(root);

System.out.println(result);
```

*Output*

```json
{"Line":1,"Direction":"incoming","LocalUsername":"xxx","AuthUsername":31223,"PeerUsername":"04232000113","Name":"04232000113","Server":23424,"Connectime":"2189msec","Duration":"0msec","DiscBy":"Remote","Reason":"cancelNormalcallclearing"}
```